# Nested web components

Tags: web-component

I am trying to build a little project using web components but I'm quite unexperienced with them and I'm kind of stuck.

I would like to write something like this in my HTML file

```html
<my-sum>
  <my-unit>
  <my-unit>
  <my-unit>
</my-sum>
```

and obtain something like

```
1 + 1 + 1
```

I don't have issues rendering `my-unit` as `1`, but I don't know how to approach the fact that `my-sum` needs to access its children (which number could vary) and render them putting a `+` in between them.

Do you have any suggestion on how to approach this?

Comment: You do it just like in regular DOM access, only limitation is the ``<my-sum>`` _childDOM_ (as in ``this.children`` is not available until the whole element is parsed. Thus you need a ``setTimeout`` in the ``connectedCallback`` to properly access its own children.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you need to consider. In your `my-sum` component, you might want to deal with **reactivity** i.e., when number of children elements change, here `<my-unit>`, you might want to **recalculate** your addition. If that is the case, you need to use [**mutation observer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Otherwise, if you just want to calculate it once, you can use `connectedCallback` event lifecycle method with `setTimeout` to query your custom element like:

```
setTimeout(() => this.querySelectorAll('my-unit'), 100);
```

Next, you must also consider your use of **shadow DOM**. If you are using it, you need a different mechanism to query the children element. It would be something like:

```
setTimeout(() => this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('my-unit'), 100);
```

If you are using shadow DOM, it means you must also use `slot` element to accept the light DOM and render it within that slot. With slot, you can use `slotchange` event to detect node changes and re-calculate the sum of `my-unit` components.

In summary, you have multiple options to acheive your goal:

- Without shadow DOM + No Reactivity: Use simple `this.querySelectorAll('my-unit')` preferably with `connectedCallback` lifecycle method
- Without shadow DOM + Reactivity: Use `querySelectorAll` combined with **mutation observer**. observer event can be setup within the `constructor` or `connnectedCallback`.
- With shadow DOM + No Reactivity: Acquire shadow DOM or slot element and query the children elements
- With shadow DOM + Reactivity: Acquire shadow DOM and then slot element - use `slotchange` event to re-calculate the sum
- With shadow DOM + Reactivity: Setup Mutation observer on **light DOM** and then query as mentioned above.